# Dropping the '-ly' in adverbs used in a negative response to a question

Tags: british-english

Two British gangsters riding in London traffic. One says: 'Have you seen him?' Other says: 'Not recent. One says: 'do you still go there?' Other says: 'Not regular.' Is this a colloquialism, idiom or just plain bad grammar.

Comment: Not an idiom but a type of dialect, a colloquialism if you prefer.

Comment: bad grammar would be my guess.

Comment: Informal conversational; has grammar only to the extent absolutely needed. Adverbs routinely drop the *-ly* in formal speech too, even in writing, these days. Do people speak like this, not in traffic, but in a business meeting? "Rare."

Answer (score 2):

If people often say it and people often do it, then it's not bad grammar. It might be a usage from a specific regional variety of English, in which case it will be regarded as non-standard, which in reality just means 'different'. This, does not constitute 'bad grammar'.

[On the other hand, if was being made up by a writer doing an *inaccurate* impression of a London gangster, then of course, in this case, it would just be bad grammar!]

I live in London most of the year and I've never heard this usage. However, this does not mean that it's not authentic. Comments here suggest that it is indeed a feature of certain varieties, which would indicate that it's a grammatical form of a specific type of English.

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: You do hear this in London (and more widely). It's not particularly common, but it wouldn't be regarded as "wrong" in context. As Mari-Lou A says, it's dialect.